# need the query string from the request to use with the input attribute of the action mapping

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

I am using struts 1.3.10. I need the query string from the request to use with the input attribute of the action mapping so that when validation fails, the forward goes to correct page without any null pointer exceptions. how can I do this? I do have the entire forward(myAction.do?foo="bar") as a form property posted throught he jsp. Plesae let me know if I am not clear on the problem definition.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `request.getQueryString()`?

Example:

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString(); //where "request" is "HttpServletRequest"
```